# What are options re: transferring ETH and ERC-20 tokens out of Mist without having to synch?

Tags: mist, synchronization, myetherwallet, address.transfer

I have some ETH and many custom tokens sitting in a Mist wallet that will take many days to synch.

I assume I can use the 'transfer from' function to move these tokens from this wallet without having to synch, using the JSON file.  Is that correct?  If so, is that the best way to do this quickly?

Grateful for all suggestions and thoughts.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Metamask chrome plugin and import a key from you `keystore` folder (location varies by OS. It's usually in a hidden folder called `./ethereum` or `/.ethereum`).

With Metamask, you import the key. You can use that with myetherwallet to send transactions and inspect balances.

This is all supposed to happen without you ever revealing your keys to anyone. It bears mentioning that you would be trusting the software you're using - that is to say your security depends on none of the tools spying/sniffing in an unexpected way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe that MyEtherWallet (www.myetherwallet.com) can also just directly import the JSON file.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you so much, @Rob Hitchens!  Very grateful!  Had been looming over me for weeks.